# Codeigniter access emails with Image as attachments (pop3 imap)

Tags: php, codeigniter, imap, pop3

I want to download to get the following information from my emails

```
sender
sender_email_address
subject
Message
attachments = array(
       all attachments
)
```

any library? suggestions? links?

Comment: Tried the official PHP IMAP extension: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php ?

Comment: I have actually, i am looking for CI library that can give little boost to my work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the library that can be used..

http://garrettstjohn.com/entry/reading-emails-with-php/

plus accessing the library, extracting email and its attachments

http://garrettstjohn.com/entry/extracting-attachments-from-emails-with-php/

Something that was missing in this extraction, was a function to process image, so I had to do it...

```
function _process_img($attach, $ext){

    $directory = "uploads";

    $path=realpath(APPPATH."../".$directory);
    $file_name="any_name_you_want_to_give".".".$ext;

    $file=$directory.$file_name;
    if(file_put_contents($path."/".$file_name, $attach)) return $file;
}
```

Hope it will help someone else too...

Answer (score 1):

I have used https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/IMAP and it worked just fine.

Good luck